# Determine the integral $\oint_{|z|=1} (\frac{1}{z}+\frac{2}{z^2}) dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Determine the integral $\oint_{|z|=1} (\frac{1}{z}+\frac{2}{z^2}) ~dz$.

My answer:
\begin{align*}
\oint_{|z|=1} (\frac{1}{z}+\frac{2}{z^2})~ dz&=\int_0^{2\pi} (\frac{1}{e^{it}}+\frac{2}{e^{2it}})ie^{it} dt
=\int_0^{2\pi} i + \frac{2i}{e^{it}} dt\\& = [it-\frac{2}{e^{it}}]^{2\pi}_0=(2\pi i-2)-(0-2)=2\pi i.
\end{align*}
Is this correct ? I'm not sure if I can calculate my complex integral like that.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that only the degree $1$ part of the pole contributes to the integral.

Comment: You mean that $\oint_{|z|=1} (\frac{1}{z}+\frac{2}{z^2}) dz=\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}$ dz ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: So why would that be the case ?

Comment: The simple reason is exactly because of your calculation here. That's why I'm not posting it as an answer, but it is an important piece of intuition to take out of this.

Answer (score 0):

We can check your answer with another method, with residues
$$\int_{|z|=1}\left(\frac1z+\frac2{z^2}\right)dz=2\pi i\ \text{Res}\left[\frac1z+\frac1{z^2};0\right]=2\pi i.$$
Seems like your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but I still wonder if my way of calculating is also correct ?